# Simplifying a Compound Statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have to simplify $\neg(s \wedge(t \vee u ) \wedge ((s \wedge t) \rightarrow u))$

I started by trying to using $(p \rightarrow q) \iff \neg p \vee q$ and DeMorgan's laws but things got messy. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DeMorgan is the way to start.  You have a negated conjunction, which becomes the disjunction of the negation of the terms.  Then a negated implication becomes a conjunction (of what?)

Comment: Using DeMorgan's you would get: ((Not S) OR Not(t OR u) OR Not((s AND t) implies u))

Comment: End result once we have used DeMorgan's on everything would be:
(not s OR (not t and not u) OR ((s and t) and not u))

Comment: I agree.  Not too much of a mess, in my opinio.

Comment: Applying Distributive Law I end up with ((not s or not t) and (not s or not u) or ((s and t) and not u)) Which seems to be just as complicated as what I was trying to simplify

Comment: Yes, I would stop with the previous version.  But simplicity is sometimes in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Would you know of any ways to simplify the previous version, or is that as simple as it gets?

Comment: If we ignore the middle term for now, you can use the distributive law to go from $\lnot s \vee (s \wedge t \wedge \lnot u)$ to $\lnot s \vee (t \wedge \lnot u)$  The second term of that combines with the middle term we ignored to give (what?)

Comment: If we take out the middle term, aren't we left with (not s or not t) OR (s and t and not u)?

Comment: I meant ignoring (or think about commuting to the end) the $(\lnot t \wedge \lnot u)$ of your solution because it got in the way of that simplification

Comment: If I take your word on the distributive application I end up not s or not u, which is very nice. I'm confused on how you used the distributive law there though, since I only know it in the form of p and (q or r) / p or (q and r).

Comment: We have $\lnot s \vee (s \wedge t \wedge \lnot u) \equiv \lnot s \vee (s \wedge (t \wedge \lnot u)) \equiv (\lnot s \vee s) \wedge (\lnot s \vee (t \wedge \lnot u)) \equiv \lnot s \vee (t \wedge \lnot u)$ the first by associativity, the second distributivity, the third recognizing the first part as True and deleting from a conjunction

Answer (score 0):

$$¬(s∧(t∨u)∧((s∧t)→u))$$

$$¬s v (¬t∧¬u) v (s∧t∧¬u)$$

$$¬s v (¬t∧t) v (s∧¬u∧¬u)$$

$$¬s v (F) v (s∧¬u)$$

$$¬s v (s∧¬u)$$

$$(¬svs) ∧ (¬sv¬u)$$

$$T ∧ (¬sv¬u)$$

$$(¬sv¬u)$$

(Final answer)

Did this question in a university class (just with different letters)